# Is using urine to clean a wound better than non-sterile water?

Tags: wound-care, first-aid

I have heard that if you are in the wilderness and need a sterile fluid to rinse a wound, urine is an acceptable choice.

Sometime ago this topic came up while discussing emergency treatment.  It was suggested that as urine is a sterile fluid it would be a good choice for rinsing an open wound.

Where good means less likely for an infection to set in as if it would if the wound was not rinsed OR if the wound was rinsed with ground or another non-sterile water source.

Does using urine helps in this regad?

Comment: Maybe carry emergency medical supplies? Like a first aid kit, at least.

Comment: Urine is definitely not sterile fluid . .  It always has pathogens /bacteria in it . .  By the way urinary tract is very very commonest site of bacterial infection

Comment: Urine is as long as you don't have an infection always sterile. It must be. However one normally cannot access this pure urine without contaminating it. As soon as you *pee* you normally get some of the bacteria in your genital area inside the first few millilitres of your urine. There's however a practise, where you clean your external meatus of your urethra (e.g. the end of the penis) thoroughly and pee for a short time off and then without stoping the process hold a bottle or something (sterile) underneath it. Urine captured this way is generally considered as as sterile as you can get it.

Comment: The alternative would of course be to make a punction with a long needle directly into your bladder, however not really an option if your in the wild.

Comment: I used to hold similar beliefs, but [current research suggests though that urine is not sterile, even in the bladder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urine#Possible_pathogens_in_urine)

Comment: It's worked for me. Including a mild,though painful infection that broke on it's own. I'd no other choice but to do that for two days,then i had it checked at my hospital. First they told me its healthy to have it not lanced andfor precaution they gave me a low dose of antibiotics for three days and let it contonue to drain if it did. It didn't and I've had no problems since. Hope this helps, I had no knowledge or experience before this happened. At least, though I never expect to be in such aa situation again, I'll know what to do.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Funny thing is, one of the "pathogens" meantioned in the article is ammonia, which will kill germs, although it will not kill all.

Comment: Has anyone here urinated on a cut??? I have. Works like a champ!
I work in construction and when Ive cut my hand or finger Ive urinated on the wound. I've had no issues with infection or scars. It's stops the bleeding almost instantly. No lie. Don't knock it till you try it.

Comment: Don’t rinse a wound with any liquid (apart from the rims of the wound). This will prevent blood clotting. Strong-bleeding wounds clean themselves by the bleeding, and tipping the wound with sterile compressions will do the job for all other wounds

Answer (score 7):

It depends

Extended contact of urine on skin will cause skin irritation and eventual breakdown. On the other hand, that water may contain flesh eating bacteria.

This is a situation of a lesser of two evils. Each wound is different and the causes numerous. The only reason you would need to "clean" a wound is if there is something in the wound that presents a hazard. Is that hazard greater then the damage urine will cause it?

Bleeding does not necessarily require cleaning. Bleeding in it's very nature is bleeding out and not in, decreasing the odds of infection.

Urine is designed to remove waste materials and isn't designed for bacteria. A UTI (Urinary Tract Infection) is normally introduced externally rather then interiorly.

As far as sterility goes, completely sterile water is uncommon. I would trust water from my water bottle more then urine, even if it does contain bacteria from my mouth.

Comment: This looks like a pretty good answer but it could be improved with some references.

Comment: I agree with @JamesJenkins here--it seems like the 'I would trust water from my water bottle more then urine, even if it does contain bacteria from my mouth.' is the crucial question (although I will say that this answer is valuable just by the fact that it points out that bleeding is generally pushing out material, and that with many wounds there would not necessarily be a good reason to irrigate, period).